# Python shell is open but not .py file?

Tags: python, shell, python-idle

I am using python 3.4.2 IDLE on windows.
When I open the IDLE shell and then open .py file, then it works,
**but when I try to open the .py file by double cliking, it just doesn't open, or proceed anything. Looks like as if nothing has happened.**

I would like to open .py file and then just press F5 to see what is going on rather than individually open all the file (I am still beginner to python, I know I can use pycharm, but at this point, just that would be good enough)

Comment: Right click on the file and select edit with IDLE.  Double left-click will by default try to run the script.

Answer (score 0):

When you double click on a .py file, it will run it using the Python Interpreter. You can right-click on the file instead and choose to open it in IDLE.